# Resize table beyond screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I've written some code that allows the user to resize each column by clicking on the column borders on the first row (much like Excel).

My problem is: I just can't make the table bigger than the window. Instead, the other columns shrink when I try this. I believe that there must be some CSS trick to do that, but just couldn't find it.

I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3e46vb23/1/).

Also, I thought that using `event.preventDefault` I would be able to stop selecting text while a column is being resized (if the cursor hovers below or above the first row). But it is not working. Any ideas why? Or how can I do it? Thanks in advance!

My code:

```js
function getMousePos(table, evt) {
  var rect = table.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}
var row1x = null,
  row1col = null,
  row1colW = null;

function row1MouseDown(e) {
  if (row1x == null) {
    var table = document.getElementById('tblMain');
    var pos = getMousePos(table, e);
    var N = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    var gap = 5;
    var i, w, ww = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      w = table.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth;
      ww += w;
      if ((pos.x > ww - gap) && (pos.x < ww + gap)) {
        row1x = pos.x;
        row1col = i;
        row1colW = table.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth;
      }
    }
  }
}

function row1MouseUp(e) {
  row1x = null;
  row1col = null;
  row1colW = null;
}

function row1MouseMove(e) {
  var table = document.getElementById('tblMain');
  var pos = getMousePos(table, e);
  var gap = 5;
  var i, w, ww = 0;
  var N = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  if (row1x == null) {
    var row1 = document.getElementById('tr1Main');
    row1.style.cursor = 'default';
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      w = table.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth;
      ww += w;
      if ((pos.x > ww - gap) && (pos.x < ww + gap)) {
        row1.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
      }
    }
  } else {
    var width = row1colW - row1x + pos.x;
    table.rows[0].cells[row1col].style.width = width + 'px';
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<body onMouseMove='row1MouseMove(event)' onMouseUp='row1MouseUp(event)'>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <table id='tblMain'>
    <tr id='tr1Main' onMouseMove='row1MouseMove(event)' onMouseDown='row1MouseDown(event)' onMouseUp='row1MouseUp(event)'>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Edit: The following changes in the JavaScript is the best I have so far, but still far from good. The table goes beyond the end of the screen, but there are some glitches.

```
function row1MouseMove(e) {
    var table = document.getElementById('tblMain');
    var pos = getMousePos(table,e);
    var gap = 5;
    var i, w, ww=0;
    var N = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    if (row1x == null) {
        var row1 = document.getElementById('tr1Main');
        row1.style.cursor = 'default';
        for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
            w = table.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth;
            ww += w;
            if ((pos.x > ww-gap) && (pos.x < ww+gap)) {
                row1.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
            }
        }
    } else {
        var width = row1colW - row1x + pos.x;
        table.rows[0].cells[row1col].style.width = width + 'px';
        for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
            if (i == row1col) {
                ww += width;
            } else {
                ww += table.rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth;
            }
        }
        table.style.width = ww + 'px';
    }
}
```

Comment: `table { width: 200%; }` works fine for me. Just remember to also have that rule: `html, body { width: 100%; }`

Comment: @lleaff If I do it, the table begins too big!

Comment: Adjust the inner rows accordingly then, e.g.: `tr { width: 50%; }`

Comment: I would like if the table could begin as a normal html table (initial column widths following content). Anyway, I couldn't make your last suggestion work on Firefox.

Comment: Just keep fidling with it, there's no reason your example can't work, it might just be a little bit complicated. CSS development is a lot of trial and error and dirty tricks you learn along the way.

Comment: Trial and error? Looks like we're running back to the Middle Ages! It will probably work if I adjust table width at run-time, just it just look ridiculous.

Comment: That describes CSS perfectly :)

Comment: I'm trying to play with table.style.width, but the result is a mess!

Comment: You might want to look for settings that constrain the table's display to the screen only. Look at things like overflow settings in your css. Or, containing divs with width settings.

Answer (score 0):

The Table will overflow outside the window by default.  Some CSS rules to look for and tweak are:

`table-layout:`
`overflow:`